# What exactly triggers main.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

By building a basic Angular CLI project, we get the following `index.html` when we run the application:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SimpleCLI</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js">
  </script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Next step is our entry point **main.ts**. Of course the name does not matter and is defined in **.angular-cli.json**. Could someone clarify the following points?

- Is it `vendor.bundle.js` which contains all Angular code and is responsible for starting the bootstrap process?
- Once the bootstrap process starts **how exactly** the application knows where to go, namely how does it trigger `main.ts`? Is it only the property

  ```
   "main": "main.ts"
  ```

  inside `.angular-cli.json` which defines that?

Comment: Inside _.angular-cli.json_ you got `"root": "src"`, `"index": "index.html"` and `"main": "main.ts"`. Both _index.html_ and _main.ts_ are located inside _src_. Therefore the applications knows where to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, only angular-cli.json references it for handling the startup of the application.

main.ts is not a module but a simple script-file, executed from top to bottom and can have any other file-name.

The only other thing that affects it as a .ts file, is tsconfig.json, which handles the transpilation to javascript. but it does so by the *.ts file-name pattern not by referencing files individually.

Answer (score 5):

1. **No Vendor.bundle.js** don't contain angular code. It contain 3rd party plugins, eg. bootstrap, jquery, jquery plugins, which we included in package.json.
   It's not responsible for bootstrapping angular application.
2. In **main.ts** file last line  **platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)** responsible for bootstraping of angular application. **platformBrowserDynamic()** part of this line indicates that we are about to boot Angular in a browser environment.

3.**The bootstrapModule()** function helps bootstrap our root module taking in the root module as its argument.

4. **AppModule** is our root module which is the entry module for our application, this can actually be any of the modules in our application but by convention AppModule is used as the root module.

5.In our **AppModule,** we then need to specify the component that will serve as the entry point component for our application. In our **app.module.ts** file where we import the entry component (conventionally AppComponent) and supply it as the only item in our bootstrap array inside the NgModule configuration object. eg. **bootstrap[AppComponent]**

Answer (score 4):

main.ts file is the entry point of our web-app.It compiles the web-app and bootstraps the AppModule to run in the browser.
It starts with importing the basic module which we need.

**platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)**

This code has reference to the parent module i.e AppModule. Hence when it executes in the browser, the file that is called is index.html. index.html internally refers to the main.ts file which calls the parent module i.e AppModule.

When AppModule is called, it calls app.module.ts which further calls the AppComponent based on the bootstrap.

**bootstrap:[AppComponent]**

In app.component.ts, there is **selector:"app-root"** which is used in the index.html file. This will display the contents present in app.component.html.

Answer (score 2):

**main.bundle.js** is the one responsible for starting the bootstrap process.

It is built by the Angular compiler based on the config read from **angular.json**, which is where it is indicated that **main.ts** is the main bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 (Angular CLI project), angular.json file contains all project information which contains information about complete project assets. In this file, main can be configured to any type script file which can then act as module starter for the configured application , as an example say start.ts.
Now start.ts will act as starting point for the application module which should ideally responsible for bootstrapping the application using platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(YourModuleStarter)